# How to return number of found rows from SELECT query

Tags: php, database, mysql, wpdb

I wrote a function which is supposed to return the number of rows found in a SELECT query but it always either seems to return 0 or an array. I have been messing around with this for about an hour now and I still can't figure it out! I'm sure I'm doing something stupidly wrong.

The MySQL Table

```
+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| postid |     ip      |        time         |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+
|   1234 | 192.168.0.1 | 2014-01-29 14:27:02 |
|   5678 | 192.168.0.2 | 2014-01-29 14:27:02 |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+
```

PHP

```
### Search for IP in database
function postviews_get_ip($id, $ip) {
    global $post, $wpdb;

    $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_postviews_ips WHERE postid = $id AND ip = $ip");

    $rowcount = $wpdb->num_rows;

    return $rowcount;
}

postviews_get_ip($id, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
//both $id and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) return the values I'm searching for in the database
```

Comment: What is the name of the table and the table prefix?

Comment: @Chittaranjan Table name is wp_postviews_ips, I'm not sure what you mean by table prefix though.

Comment: Removing "$wpdb->" from $wpdb->wp_postviews_ips seemed to do the trick!

Comment: That's the reason I had asked for the table name and prefix. All wordpress tables have a prefix which you set during setting up the wordpress site. Here are more details on [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Database_Table_Prefix) Please check my updated answer with correct use of table name.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you are merely trying to get a count, `$wpdb->get_var();` along with using `COUNT()` in your sql will be better:

```
### Search for IP in database
function postviews_get_ip($id, $ip) {
    global $post, $wpdb;

    $rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->wp_postviews_ips WHERE postid = $id AND ip = '$ip'");

    return $rowcount;
}

postviews_get_ip($id, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
//both $id and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) return the values I'm searching for in the database
```

As to what went wrong in your previous example, you weren't assigning your `$wpdb->get_results()` instance to a variable, and without it `$wpdb->num_rows;` is just going to return zero as it isn't actually pulling from the instance of the query, but rather the global $wbdb object.

If you do want to use `get_results()`:

```
### Search for IP in database
function postviews_get_ip($id, $ip) {
    global $post, $wpdb;

    $ipquery= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_postviews_ips WHERE postid = $id AND ip = '$ip'");
    $rowcount = $ipquery->num_rows;
    return $rowcount;
}

postviews_get_ip($id, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
//both $id and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) return the values I'm searching for in the database
```

But I wouldn't see the need for that unless you needed the results, in which case I would just return the `$ipquery` object and use `num_rows` on it when I needed it:

```
### Search for IP in database
function postviews_get_ip($id, $ip) {
    global $post, $wpdb;

    $ipquery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_postviews_ips WHERE postid = $id AND ip = '$ip'");
    return $ipquery;
}

$someVariable = postviews_get_ip($id, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
//both $id and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) return the values I'm searching for in the database

echo $someVariable->num_rows;
```

Comment: Small addition. You should always use prepare (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) when executing any queries to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Actually that shouldnt be a small addition, that's very important not to make your code exploitable via sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the query is wrong. `$ip` is string so you should put single quote around that as below

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postviews_ips WHERE postid = $id AND ip = '$ip'");
```

Comment: Tried this and it still returns 0.