# Isn't Returning Value While Using SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}

Tags: php, functions, wp-query, wpdb, meta-query

I'm trying to count rows in sql table using SELECT COUNT(*) for the post view count. My code is

```
    function get_post_views($offset=0, $post_id){
        global $wpdb;
        $get_visit_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}" . VISITS_TABLE .   " WHERE object_id = '{$post_id}' AND datetime > '2021-09-07 0:0:0' AND datetime < '2021-09-09 0:0:0'";
        
        $visits_total =  $wpdb->get_var( $get_visit_query, 0 );

        $combined_views = (int)$get_visit_query + (int)$offset;

        return $combined_views;}
```

And if I get the rows count value($combined_views) from VISITS_TABLE, I will change the meta_value in wp_post_meta table with the code

```
     function set_post_views($offset=0, $post_id) {
        $visits_total = apply_filters('get_post_views', $offset, $post_id);

        update_post_meta($post_id, POST_VIEW_COUNT_KEY, $visits_total); 
    }
```

The problem is that **the meta_value is 0** all the time. *(Post view count is 0 all the time)* 
 I tried [this tread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131687/how-to-return-number-of-found-rows-from-select-query), but didn't work for me sadly.

Comment: What is VISITS_TABLE? That's not WP core.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $combined_views = (int)$get_visit_query + (int)$offset;
```

This doesn't make much sense. `$get_visit_query` is a string (your query). Converting it to `int` returns in `0`, [see this snippet](https://3v4l.org/j5dvR). Instead it should be

```
$combined_views = (int)$visits_total + (int)$offset;
```

Sidenote: Are you actually hooking the function via [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)? If not, `apply_filters('get_post_views', ..)` will not have the desired effect. Using the function name doesn't magically add it to the filters, you need to explicitly define it e.g. via `add_filter('get_post_views', 'get_post_views', 10, 2);`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @kero and I have applied what you asked me to do but doesn't work either. I changed the code to `$combined_views = (int)$visits_total + (int)$offset;` as you said and defined
`add_filter('get_post_views', array($this, 'get_post_views'), 10, 2);` above but no changed..